# Multi-select Filter Search in Laravel 4

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, query-builder

I need help/guidance in developing a multi-select filter search for my Laravel 4 app.

I have a table in my database called 'accounts'. This table is linked to other tables in the database via the following relationships:

'users' via belongs to (User model has a has many relationship to accounts)
'account_types' via belongs to (AccountType model has a has one relationship to accounts)

In my view I would like 3 multi-select boxes, company names (taken from the accounts table 'company_name' field), account managers (taken from the account_managers table, 'first_name' and 'last_name' fields) and account type (taken from the account_types table, 'type' field).

When a user selects values from these multi-select boxes and submits the form, I need to search the relevant tables and bring back the results. I don't want to use joins for this, as it is very slow. Especially, when bringing back values for the multi-select boxes.

If possible I would like to use Eloquent relationships in a way that brings back the results quickly.

I have this working with joins and query strings but it is very slow, up to 10 to 15 seconds.

I hope someone can help me out with this. Cheers.

Comment: Can you post your current code that do the search that take 10 to 15 seconds? In other hand, are you paginating you results?

Comment: Have you tried eager loading your relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have this working like a charm now by implementing select2, rather than simply loading all contacts in one go. Works much nicer too.

Here's my index method in AdminContactsController.php:

```
public function index()
{

    $contact_names_value = explode(',', Input::get('contact_names_value'));
    $accounts_value = explode(',', Input::get('accounts_value'));
    $account_managers_value = explode(',', Input::get('account_managers_value'));

    // In the view, there is a dropdown box, that allows the user to select the amount of records to show per page. Retrive that value or set a default.
    $perPage = Input::get('perPage', 10);

    // This code retrieves the order from  that has been selected by the user by clicking on table ciolumn titles. The value is placed in the session and is used later in the Eloquent query and joins.
    $order = Session::get('contact.order', 'cname.asc');
    $order = explode('.', $order);

    $message = Session::get('message');

    $default = ($perPage === null ? 10 : $perPage);

    $contacts_trash = Contact::contactsTrash($order)->get();

    $this->layout->content = View::make('admin.contacts.index', array(
        'contacts'          => Contact::contacts($order, $contact_names_value, $accounts_value, $account_managers_value, $perPage)->paginate($perPage)->appends(array('accounts_value' => Input::get('accounts_value'), 'account_managers_value' => Input::get('account_managers_value'))),
        'contacts_trash'    => $contacts_trash,
        'perPage'           => $perPage,
        'message'           => $message,
        'default'           => $default
    ));
}
```

My scopeContacts method in my Contact.php model:

```
public function scopeContacts($query, $order, $contact_names_value, $accounts_value, $account_managers_value, $perPage)
{
    $query->leftJoin('accounts', 'accounts.id', '=', 'contacts.account_id')
        ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'accounts.user_id')
        ->orderBy($order[0], $order[1])
        ->select(array('contacts.*', DB::raw('contacts.id as cid'), DB::raw('CONCAT(contacts.first_name," ",contacts.last_name) as cname'), DB::raw('CONCAT(users.first_name," ",users.last_name) as amname')));

    if (empty($contact_names_value[0])) {
        //
    } else {
        $query = $query->whereIn('contacts.id', $contact_names_value);
    }

    if (empty($accounts_value[0])) {
        //
    } else {
        $query = $query->whereIn('accounts.id', $accounts_value);
    }

    if (empty($account_managers_value[0])) {
        //
    } else {
        $query->whereIn('users.id', $account_managers_value);
    }
}
```

Here's my JS code:

```
$('#contact_names_value').select2({
    placeholder: 'Search contacts',
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: '/admin/get-contact',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                contact_names_value: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            return {results: data};
        }
    },
    tags: true
});
```

Here's my method getContactByName implemented in my AdminContactsController.php (similar methods implemented for users and accounts) code:

```
public function getContactByName()
{
    $name = Input::get('contact_names_value');
    return Contact::select(array('id', DB::raw('concat(first_name," ",last_name) as text')))->where(DB::raw('concat(first_name," ",last_name)'), 'like', "%$name%")->get();
}
```

Notice during my select statement, I do a DB::raw and set the 'first_name' and 'last_name' fields to be selected as 'text'. I think this was one of the major issues, as the plugin requires 'id' and 'text' to function.

My route was simply:

```
Route::get('admin/get-contact', 'AdminContactsController@getContactByName');
```